# Creating numpy array of custom objects gives error "SystemError: error return without exception set"

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to use numpy to store some custom objects I've made.  The following is a simplified version of my program

```
import numpy as np

class Element:
    def __init__(self): pass

a = Element()
periodicTable = np.array(range(7*32)).reshape((7,32))
periodicTable[0][0] = a
```

However when I run this I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dan/Desktop/a.py", line 9, in <module>
    periodicTable[0][0] = a
SystemError: error return without exception set
```

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong - as far as I can tell everything I've done should be legal.  The cryptic error message itself isn't very helpful - I believe that is a numpy issue however I've been unable to identify my problem.

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but why are you trying to stick arbitrary Python objects into an array of dtype `int32`? Also, if you want to generate an empty array, there's `numpy.zeros`, `ones`, or `empty`. You don't need to create a Python list with `range` to initialize it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@user2357112 identified the problem: you are assigning an `Element` instance to a numpy array that holds integers.   This is what I get when I try something similar:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.__version__
'1.7.1'
>>> p = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> class Foo:
...     pass
... 
>>> p[0] = Foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
SystemError: error return without exception set
>>>
```

It is not surprising that this is not allowed.  The cryptic error message, however, is almost certainly a numpy bug.

One way to fix the issue is to use an array of type `object`.  Change this line:

```
    periodicTable = np.array(range(7*32)).reshape((7,32))
```

to this:

```
    periodicTable = np.empty((7,32), dtype=object)
```

---

*Update*

In numpy 1.10.1, the error message is still a bit cryptic:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.__version__
'1.10.1'    
>>> p = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> class Foo:
...     pass
...  
>>> p[0] = Foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: Foo instance has no attribute '__trunc__'
```

---

*Update 2*

The error message is better is later versions of numpy:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.__version__
Out[2]: '1.12.1'

In [3]: class Foo:
   ...:     pass
   ...: 

In [4]: p = np.array([1, 2, 3])

In [5]: p[0] = Foo()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-739d5e5f795b> in <module>()
----> 1 p[0] = Foo()

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Foo'
```